# Need to update pip but it points to an old project

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

im getting this warning:

> WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.1.2 is
> available. You should consider upgrading via the
> '/Users/carloscastaneda/PycharmProjects/Day32_Birthday Wisher
> start/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Why do I have to update pip via that old project? Aren't package files contained in a separate folder?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to upgrade pip. What you get is only a warning letting you know that you are running an old version which might cause issues when installing packages. But if package installations are succesfull you can keep running the old version of pip if you think upgrading pip is too much work.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a copy of pip (and Python) in each virtual environment you create. Each of these need to be updated separately. If you activate the virtual environment you are using, then "pip -m pip install --upgrade pip" will update pip for that virtual environment only.